# Trying To Delete Left-Over Malware Files

Tags: terminal, security, permission, macos, malware

An annoying piece of malware that pretends to be a new Safari / Sonoma security feature has deposited itself and its associated files inside my `System/Library/`... In short, I need to delete a folder hierarchy out of `System/Library/etc/etc` but everything I've tried hasn't worked. To be clear, I'm not trying to purge my library or go on some crazy deleting binge - I want to selectively and deliberately delete a few files I *know* are malware.

Obviously dragging them into the trash doesn't work.

I've ensured the offending folder is unlocked in **Get Info** and, while the "system" user has "read & write" privilege, "wheel", and "everyone", only have "read only", and when I go to change this I'm told I don't have the necessary permission (although, as admin, I should).

I've used Terminal commands like `rm -rf` but I'm told I don't have the permissions. After disabling System Integrity Protection, I'm instead told it's a "Read Only File System".

I have a backup of every file I need here, but it seems "reasonable" that I should, as admin, be able to kill some malware without having to nuke my laptop from orbit or, worse, download one of those "Mac Cleaner" apps.

Is there a reliable way to delete files? It's hard to tell here what's MacOS acting in my best interests, and what's malware.

Comment: How did you determine it's malware? Exactly what is the file? The System/Library is part of the immutable system volume, so you would have discovered a very serious security breach indeed if what you say is true.

Comment: it calls itself "ask you" in order to send notifications and "confirm that you're not a robot you need to click allow". Its folder hierarchy includes the name "AskPermission".

Comment: it initially appeared as if it were part of a CAPTCHA, like an extra layer of security for Safari, then after that just spammed notifications, pretending to be system alerts, trying to get me to "update my antivirus"

Comment: Can you supply the full file path? Certainly the behaviour sounds like a webpage/web notification trying to trick you, but how did you ascertain the cause was in /System? As Tetsujin says, that is normally completely off-limits to anyone -- you, me, malware. I would recommend using Malwarebytes, but agree that "cleaning" apps would do nothing good here.

Comment: Sorry - made a fool of myself - let me double check that